# Grouping elements based on their sum

Tags: r, sum, grouping

I have a vector `x <- c(1:10)`, my problem statement is that if my element sum is greater than or equal to 10 then store them in a different object,such that my output would look like 
`a=(1,2,3,4); b=(5); c1=(6); d=(7); e=(8); f=(9); g=(10)` 
I have tried this

```
x <- c(1:10)

for(i in x) {
  if(sum(x) <= 10)
  {
    .
    .
    .
  }

}
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a double `cumsum` to create a grouping variable and `split` the `vector` ('x') based on that.

```
lst <- split(x, cumsum(cumsum(x)>10))
```

If we need individual objects in the global environment, `list2env` can be used (but not recommended)

```
list2env(setNames(lst, letters[seq_along(lst)]), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```